# get the permission of the file in a header of a tar with struct stat

Tags: c, tar

I'm creating a programe to manage tar file.
I print the permission of the file with the struct stat :

```
printf("%d\n", buff->st_mode); /* I get a number like 33152 */
```

but I need to put the permission in my mode[8] of struct header :

```
typedef struct  s_head
{
    char        name[100];
    char        mode[8];
    char        uid[8];
    char        gid[8];
    char        size[12];
    char        mtime[12];
    char        chksum[8];
    char        linkflag;
    char        linkname[100];
    char        magic[8];
    char        uname[32];
    char        gname[32];
    char        devmajor[8];
    char        devminor[8];
}               t_head;
```

and when I print mode i should get somthing like this 000600 (for rw-------)
but how could I convert my st_mode in a char * with the right writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use octal.

The number OP has is an `int` with a value of 33152.  By printing this as an octal number the usual "rwx" settings are more apparent: 100600 .

```
// printf("%d\n", buff->st_mode); // OP gets a number like 33152
printf("%o\n", buff->st_mode);    // 100600
snprintf(s_head.mode, sizeof(s_head.mode), "%06o", buff->st_mode); // "100600"
```